# openni_camera/openni_launch fuerte repository access denial

Tags: openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I cannot clone the ros openni_camera mercurial repository , authentication failure.

Even after I registered at : kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_camera

After I login via web, it shows:

> Access Denied
>
> Sorry, you do not have permission to
> access that resource.
>
> Requested resource:
> /openni/openni_camera
>
> If you think you need greater access
> rights, please request support.

I cannot access the repo via terminal, after type in the username and password.

Is there a specific username/password for downloading the repository?

Any help is really appreciated!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76825/openni_camera/openni_launch-fuerte-repository-access-denial/) by [mzhu.upenn](https://answers.ros.org/users/6424/mzhu.upenn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

openni_camera has been moved to github: https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1